# Why are only the first letters converted to lowercase letters?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main( void)
{
   char  str[100];
   int   ndx;
   
   printf("Input your name in uppercase letters.\n");
   scanf("%c", &str);
   for ( ndx= 0; ndx < strlen( str); ndx++)
   {
      str[ndx] = (char)tolower( str[ndx]);
   }
   printf( "%s\n", str);
   return 0;
}
```

If I write JAMES
it prints just j
I want james
please help me

I'd like to convert the characters I received on scanf to lowercase. I'm a very newbie. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Improve Your Naming Conventions.

Comment: don't use `strlen(str)` in the loop as it'll be called again each iteration. Store that value in a variable instead

Comment: The `%c` format specifier in `scanf` indicates that you want to read a single character.

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings, this error (as explained by paddy) would have been caught if you had.

Comment: It's because your `scanf()` call is using `%c` instead of `%s` like it should.

Answer (score 0):

You used `%c` with `scanf`; it only *read* one letter (`%c` means "extract a single `char`"). If you want to read a string into the buffer, try using `%99s` to read up to 99 characters into your buffer as a C-style string (leaving the final character in your 100 `char` array for the `NUL` terminator).

Comment: or just use fgets

Comment: @SuperStormer: If they want to reach the end of a line (assuming they don't run out of space first), sure. `%s` stops at any whitespace, which may or may not be their intent.